# Is there a free WinForms control similar to Telerik's RadDock?

Tags: winforms, telerik, dock

I'm looking to create an interface which has drag-drop-dock functionality like Visual Studio. Telerik offers exactly what I'm looking for:
http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms/dock.aspx

Trouble is, it will cost $1000. This is a side project and I don't have a budget for that. Does anyone know of a similar control which is free and/or open source? Google didn't turn up any results.

Thanks

Comment: [DockPanelSuite](http://dockpanelsuite.com/) - The Visual Studio inspired docking library for .NET WinForms. [DockPanel Suite Documentation](http://docs.dockpanelsuite.com/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up going more low-level and using OpenTk GameWindow and GWEN, which contains docking.

GWEN - GUI Without Extravagant Nonsense
https://github.com/garrynewman/GWEN

It's absolutely great, but unfortunately the original project is abandoned. There are a ton of forks at different states. I've personally had a lot of success with it.